# Rolling back a Rails migrations with execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know what Rails does when rolling back a migration file, if it has an `execute` with some raw SQL statement.

Here is a contrived example:

```
def change
  add_column :my_table, :new_column
  execute "update my_table set new_column = some_value where some_condition"
end
```

When rolling back this migration, does Rails silently ignore the `execute` portion of the migration?

Comment: You want to know what will be happen or how rollback this change?

Comment: @dx7 As written in the question, I'd like to know what Rails will do if I try to rollback this change.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to try :-) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in command_recorder.rb (in the active record gem) then you'll see that some migration methods (eg `add_column`) have a corresponding `invert_foo` method that reverses the change. If there is no corresponding `invert` method then rails will raise an error. This is the case for it has no way of knowing how to reverse an arbitrary statement.

If you would like your migration to be reversible you need to tell rails how to reverse it. The general form for this is

```
reversible do |direction|
  direction.up { ... }
  direction.down {...}
end
```

The up and down methods can be called as many times as you need and will only yield to the block if the direction matches whether the migration is running or being rolled back.

In your case this would just be

```
reversible do |direction|
  direction.up { execute "..." }
end
```

Since you don't need to undo changes to the column if the column is about to be dropped.

Comment: Did not know this one. Thank you. It might have been faster to just try, but someone else might be looking for the same answer on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume as much.  You should split this into an up and a down migration.

Down should look something like this:

```
def down
  raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
end
```